# function template overloading

Tags: c++

Consider the following program.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum (int & a, int & b)
{
  cout <<" NOn template function "<<endl;
  return a+b;
}

template <typename T>
int sum ( const T & a, const T & b)
{
  cout<<"Template Generated .."<<endl;
  return a+b;
};


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  cout <<sum(10,20)<<endl;;
}
```

**What is the problem:**

I was expecting the sum() of non template function to be invoked. But in my output
template initialized function is invoked. Is it not part of the function template overloading.

Kindly point of what mistake i am doing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `int&` cannot bind to a temporary, so the non-template version cannot be used. It is the same as doing `int& i = 10;` which is not allowed.

`10` and `20` are prvalues (3.10):

> A prvalue (“pure” rvalue) is an rvalue that is not an xvalue. [
>   Example: The result of calling a function whose return type is not a
>   reference is a prvalue. **The value of a literal such as 12, 7.3e5, or
>   true is also a prvalue.** —end example ]

Answer (score 4):

> I was expecting the sum() of non template function to be invoked.

You're passing rvalues, which cannot be bind to non-const reference. Hence the template version is selected.

Change `int &` to `int const &` OR `int`, the first version will be selected:

- http://ideone.com/yKAFLP which uses `int const&`.
- http://ideone.com/nlP27g which uses `int`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Nawaz, I was expecting your response ;).

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
T sum ( const T & a, const T & b)
{
  cout<<"Template Generated .."<<endl;
  return a+b;
};
```

**T** `sum ( const T & a, const T & b)`  change `int` to `T`